# Creating an XML Log file in Java

Tags: java, xml, logging

For our J2SE application, we want to create an XML log file.  Events will be logged as they happen.  There will be perhaps four or five types of events that can happen (for example, key strokes, mouse clicks, and also more application-specific events), each with their own structure.  The only attribute that these different event types have in common is a time stamp.

Is there a standard way of doing this?  (I considered using Log4j XMLLayout, but that seems to only record messages as text strings without a structured format.)  One thing we are considering using is JAXB.

Comment: Since they have something in common, make an Abstract Super Class which all of your events can extend so that they get a time stamp field, and methods. As for the rest, I do not know the answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Would recommend Logback, which gives you full flexibility in formatting (e.g. via XML) your output.  I suspect this is the closest tool to what you need - I can't really imagine the XML you'd want to output in being coded in to some library since that's going to be very application-dependent.  But in any case it's a logging framework that has suited our needs better than log4j and is good to be familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Java includes a significant logging feature described here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/index.html. You should be able to create a custom Formatter to take your custom LogRecord objects and turn them into appropriate XML.